# Problems embedding youtube video

Tags: html, youtube, embed

I am starting to get crazy with this code. It's so simple but it doesn't work and I can't understand why.

I am trying to embed a youtube video in a HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="font-family: 'NeubauGrotesk55Normal'; font-size: 32px; text-transform: uppercase; color: #0066b3; margin-left: 20px;">Add title</div>
    <div style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Georgia', 'Times New Roman', times, serif; color: #333333; margin-left: 20px; margin-top:20px;">Add text</div>

    <div style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top:20px;"><iframe width="853" height="480" src="//www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/rzp7wHnX6jc?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `http:` in `... src="//www.youtube...` -> `... src="http://www.youtube...`

Comment: That was an easy one! I didn't notice I was missing the http part. I just copied the code from youtube, so weird.

Answer (score 3):

you're missing `http:` on your YouTube link

Comment: That was an easy one! I didn't notice I was missing the http part. I just copied the code from youtube, so weird.